# Multiple Callbacks instead of use Delegates in swift

Tags: swift, callback, delegates, closures

I am developing an app that have to send commands to a machine. I know how to use delegates to propagate the response of the commands that I receive in an Input Stream. But probably is better to use Callbacks for some commands who have to update the UI.

I have searched for a good solution to code this, but I couldn't find it.

In this code, for example:

```
class NetworkService {

    var onComplete: ((result: String)->())? //an optional function

    func fetchDataFromUrl(url: String) {
        API.request(.GET, url) { result in
            onComplete?(result: result) 
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    let networkService = NetworkService()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        networkService.onComplete = { result in
            print("I got \(result) from the server!")
        }
    }
}
```

It's ok, I can use onComplete as a callback, but... I need multiple callbacks for multiple commands:

- Have I to create a "var" with the callback for each different command?
- Is there a way to have an array or a queue with the callbacks?
- What will happen If I don't receive a response for a command, and I send again the command? I suppose that I have to handle timeouts in some way.
- What could be the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried notifications? on your ViewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(dataFetched), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "dataFetched"), object: nil)
    networkService.fetchDataFromUrl(url: url)
}

func dataFetched(_ notification: Notification) {
    // do your stuff with notification.object
}
```

on your NetworkService class

```
func fetchDataFromUrl(url: String) { 
    API.request(.GET, url)
}

func dataFetched(result: Any) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "dataFetched"), object: result)
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to store the callback closures in some way, because one method request the information, but the information comes later in a other method (in a protocol of the delegate). So I need to access to the closure in another method and I think that I have to store the closure as a var.

Comment: ok, your code:  API.request(.GET, url) { result in  } say the contrary, I edited my response in the case the response was in another method

Comment: I could use Notifications, but also I can use delegates. I am trying to do that with callbacks and closures, because is more clear. And I think that I have to create a var for each closure, but maybe there is another way or pattern.